# Pentaho components integration

Tags: hive, pentaho

I am very new to Pentaho.
What I want to do is to submit a Hive Query to a Hadoop Cluster and analyse the results by creating correlations or by computing trends. I managed to submit a Hive query allready via the Pentaho data Integration. But I dont know how to analyze it. I have seen that there are many other Pentaho components as Weka. How can I integrate Data Integration with Weka and a Visualisation tool? Is there something that includes all of these components?

Answer (score 0):

Weka integration with the Pentaho suite is available in the Enterprise Edition.

If you are using Pentaho Community Edition and are looking for visualization and other BI tools, I recommend Webdetails' CTools plugins for the Pentaho BI Server (CE edition):

http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools.html